# Interactive Plotting for Python Locally

Tags: python, plot, interactive, bokeh

I am trying to recreate bokeh's crossfilter plot locally, because my company has a lot of restrictions. I cannot configure the firewall in my favor.

I keep getting this error:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

How can I recreate this plot locally?:

http://104.236.246.80:5006/bokeh/crossfilter/#

[image]

Comment: this link has the neccesary files to recreate it https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/bokeh/2StCzFnKj_0/lTb2V8Kc8AEJ

Comment: I forgot to mention I tried the source code and it did not work for me

Comment: What OS are you running this from? If Windows there may be a block in the [bokeh-server](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/E59coBXb7Z0) part of the equation

Comment: I am running windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Not sure if this would help but I'm watching a bokeh video where the speaker [mentions](https://youtu.be/nar7u17qkOU?t=4763) the autogenerated html js code reaching out over the network to download the Bokeh.js source. He suggests there's a way to construct things that avoid the network connectivity behavior, probably through some local copy of the Bokeh javascript.